# How to implement a Qt / Qt Creator project with test scaffold

Tags: qt, unit-testing, testing, build, qt-creator

I have a project I'm working on and I'd like to add a lightweight test scaffold to probe / regression test some of the classes. One way to go about this is to have a secondary executable target that runs the various tests.

What's the standard way of carrying this out in Qt / Qt Creator? To create a second project in the same directory and import some of the same code files, or to somehow implement two executable targets within the same project? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QTestLib` is probably what you are looking for:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/gettingstarted-develop.html#qt-utilities

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial1.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: you should have probably linked 5.1 though, or at least both.

Comment: 4.8 is the most common one referred to by Google currently.  The QTestLib wasn't listed as one of the things updated heavily by Qt5.

Comment: No no... 4.8 should not be recommended anymore, especially for new code. Also, QTestLib actually did get significant changes, i.e. source incompatible in Qt 5.0. So some stuff (like Q_SKIP) will not work anymore if someone starts using it.

Comment: Good to know.  I haven't switched up to 5.1 currently... I'm holding out a little bit for the official iOS support.  Thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: Official iOS tech preview is in 5.1 already, actually. 5.2 will have an even more thorough support.

Answer (score 0):

One project = one executable. There's nothing wrong with having one source file being used in multiple projects. You're free to factor out tested code into a static library that's then used by both your application and your test harness. That way you won't have to type in the source files twice.